# JavaScript adding "return" method to an iterator doesn't properly close the iterator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, es6-class

I am learning the JavaScript ES6 iterator pattern and came across this problem:

```js
const counter = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const iter = counter[Symbol.iterator]();
iter.return = function() {
  console.log("exiting early");
  return { done: true };
};

for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i >= 3) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log('---');
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
}

// 1
// 2
// 3
// exiting early
// ---
// 4
// 5
```

So I added a `return` method definition to the iterator that I extracted from an array. Although the return method got called, it didn't actually close the iterator. By contrast, if I define the iterator `return` method in definition, it will work as expected:

```js
class Counter {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let count = 1;
    return {
      next() {
        if (count <= 5) {
          return {
            done: false,
            value: count++
          }
        } else {
          return {
            done: true,
            value: undefined
          }
        }
      },
      return() {
        console.log('exiting early');
        return { done: true, value: undefined };
      }
    }
  }
}

const myCounter = new Counter();
iter = myCounter[Symbol.iterator]();
for (let i of myCounter) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i >= 3) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log('---');
for (let i of myCounter) {
  console.log(i);
}

// 1
// 2
// 3
// exiting early
// ---
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

My question is, why did I get this unexpected behavior? I assume that if the `return` method didn't get called, then the iterator will not close until it reaches the very end by calling `next`. But adding `return` property will properly "call" the `return` method since I got the console log, but doesn't actually terminate the iterator even if I returned `{ done: true }` in the `return` method.

Comment: I wonder if the documentation for [Array values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values#Iteration_using_.next) method explains this - look for the warning text *One-use: the array iterator object is one use or temporary object*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your two `return` methods actually close the iterator. To achieve that, they need to record the new state of the iterator, and by that cause the `next` method to also return `{done: true}` in all subsequent calls - that's what "closed" actually means.

We can see this behaviour in action with a generator:

```js
const iter = function*(){ yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; }();
console.log(iter.next());
console.log(iter.return());
console.log(iter.next());
```

Your first snippet has the problem that you've overwritten `iter.return`, and your method gets called (as seen from the log) but it never actually closes `iter`. The underlying problem is that array iterators *cannot be closed*, they don't normally have a `return` method at all. You'd have to overwrite the `iter.next` method as well to simulate this.

Your second snippet has the problem that it's not actually trying to iterate the `iter`, but it's iterating the `myCounter` twice which creates a new iterator object for each loop. Instead we need to use a `[Symbol.iterator]` method that returns the same object multiple times, easiest done by having `Counter` implement the iterator interface itself. We can now reproduce the unexpected behaviour:

```js
class Counter {
  count = 1;
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this;
  }
  next() {
    if (this.count <= 5) {
      return {done: false, value: this.count++ };
    } else {
      return {done: true, value: undefined};
    }
  }
  return() {
    console.log('exiting early');
    return { done: true, value: undefined };
  }
}

const iter = new Counter();
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i >= 3) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log('---');
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

To fix the behaviour, we would close the iterator by having the `return` method set the count beyond 5:

```js
class Counter {
  count = 1;
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this;
  }
  next() {
    if (this.count <= 5) {
      return {done: false, value: this.count++ };
    } else {
      return {done: true, value: undefined};
    }
  }
  return() {
    this.count = 6;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log('exiting early');
    return { done: true, value: undefined };
  }
}

const iter = new Counter();
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i >= 3) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log('---');
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i); // not executed!
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I guess my confusion came from the fact that array iterators **cannot be closed** and I didn't know that, and I wrote a bad example for demonstrating what I got confused about. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't know it either :-) However, even if they could, your overwritten `return` would have needed to call the original `return` method on the iterator to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Your example can be simplified as

```
let count = 1;
const iter = {
  [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; },
  next() {
    if (count <= 5) {
      return {
        done: false,
        value: count++
      }
    } else {
      return {
        done: true,
        value: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  return() {
    console.log('exiting early');
    return { done: true, value: undefined };
  }
};

for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i >= 3) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log('---');
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

so `iter` is just a normal object. You are passing it to a `for..of` loop twice.

You are making incorrect assumptions about how the interface for iterators works. The core issue is that there is nothing in this code that stores and tracks the fact that `iter` has returned `done: true` once, and thus should continue to do so. If that is the behavior you want, you need to do that yourself, e.g.

```
let count = 1;
let done = false;
const iter = {
  [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; },
  next() {
    if (!done && count <= 5) {
      return {
        value: count++
      }
    } else {
      done = true;
      return { done };
    }
  },
  return() {
    done = true;
    console.log('exiting early');
    return { done };
  }
};
```

A `for..of` loop essentially calls `.next()` until the return result is `done: true`, and calls `.return` in some cases. It is up to the implementation of the iterator itself to ensure that it properly enters a "closed" state.

All of this can also be simplified by using a generator function, since generator objects have that internal "closed" state included automatically as a side-effect of the function having returned, e.g.

```
function* counter() {
  let counter = 1;
  while (counter <= 5) yield counter++;
}

const iter = counter();
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i >= 3) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log('---');
for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I didn't know the so-called 'closed' is up to the implementation itself